# Remove String in one text file from another text file

Tags: powershell

I have two text files.  One has all servers on the domain (servers_all.txt) and the other has only the virtual servers (virtual_servers.txt).  I want to get the difference between the two so I can find the physical servers.  I have been tring compare-object to no avail

```
Compare-Object (gc servers_all.txt) (gc .\VIRTUAL_SERVERS.TXT) -IncludeEqual
```

Is there a way I can remove the servers listed in virtual_servers.txt from servers_all.txt.

Both txt files are formatted the same way with only the server names in a single column  ie:

```
ServerA
ServerB
ServerC
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare-Object is somewhat obtuse (to put it mildly).  I avoid it.

```
$VirtualServers = Get-Content .\VIRTUAL_SERVERS.TXT;
$NonVirtualServers = Get-Content servers_all.txt | Where-Object { $_ -notin $VirtualServers };
```

The only thing to beware of here is file formatting errors like leading or trailing whitespace.  If you want to handle that, you could do something like:

```
$VirtualServers = Get-Content .\VIRTUAL_SERVERS.TXT | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() };
$NonVirtualServers = Get-Content servers_all.txt | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } | Where-Object { $_ -notin $VirtualServers };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$all = 'a','b','c','d'
$virtual = 'b','c'

Compare-Object $all $virtual -PassThru
```

->

```
a
d
```